# Problem with HTML tags for PHP form submission

Tags: html

I'm looking to separate the form you're going to see shortly into two separate areas, the single input field and 3 separate submit buttons with different values for each (which is important in the php for determining the selection of the user). As a disclaimer, I'm by trade a backend developer, so HTML isn't my strongest area, but was essential for this project.

The PHP code, for this questions problem, is irrelevant, as I've determined the problem to be from the HTML and not the PHP. The PHP is not being run, as there are several debugging lines within said PHP which would return an error if it was the source of the issue. I've concluded, as none of these errors appear, that there is an issue calling the PHP file within the HTML. I've spent a bit searching other people's problems, but am unable to find a similar issue. In addition, I'm sure anyone with good HTML knowledge will quickly see the poor writing of this HTML, which I'm sure contributes to the issues, however, the stylesheet already has the frontend designed around this HTML layout, which, although can be changed if absolutely essential, would be a hassle if not necessary.

I'm paraphrasing the HTML into the section where the issue arises as the rest is unrelated content from the rest of the site, and yes, the PHP file is required at the top of the code.

```
<ul id="betValue">
                <li id="gameBalance"><h3>Balance: <?=$balance1?></h3></li>
                <li><h3>Bet Amount:</h3></li>
                <li><form name="bet" id="betAmount"><input type="number" name="betAmount"></form></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="betSelect">
                <li><button form="bet" type="submit" name="blackBet" formmethod="post" formaction="betconfirm.php"><a>Black</a></button></li>
                <li><button form="bet" type="submit" name="greenBet" formmethod="post" formaction="betconfirm.php"><a>Green</a></button></li>
                <li><button form="bet" type="submit" name="redBet"formmethod="post" formaction="betconfirm.php"><a>Red</a></button></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: If you say that "php" is not relevant, then why the "php" tag?

Comment: What problems are you having exactly and what is the question really about?

Comment: Good point, will remove, not entirely sure what the thought process was.

Comment: The problem is, however I formatted the form input of the number and the submission buttons, it doesn't call the PHP code. When you click the button on the webpage it should either input a database entry or echo an error, and since neither happens, the source is within this HTML I provided, whether it doesn't find it a valid form or an incorrect formaction, I'm not sure, HTML isn't my bread and butter.

Comment: What does the browser console show when one of the submit buttons is pressed?

Comment: No response on console, clicking on any of the buttons doesn't report anything to console.

Comment: We need to see how you're trying to call the PHP from the form. Plus, is this running on your PC or is it hosted? If on your own PC, how are you using this? Using an HTTP protocol or directly as `file:///`?

Comment: Btw, the "form" itself should have the action and method, not the inputs.

Comment: This is hosted on a domain, the way I'm trying to call the PHP to activate from the form is by putting the formaction to the PHP file and putting the functionality under an if statement which checks if $_POST['betAmount'] is set and then proceeding to the functionality I attributed to it.

Comment: So I should place the formaction and method under the form in the line above and pressing the buttons will reference the method/action?

Comment: Usually forms use `<form action="your_file.php" method="post"> Inputs etc... </form>`. I've seen what you're using before, but I don't think that this applies. If you're trying to pass inputs to a PHP file after, then you'd need something like `$input_1=$_POST['input_1'];` etc. Is *that* what you want to achieve?

Comment: Well yeah me either, the general use for the form tags in HTML is for like account creation with defined fields and a single submit, but I'm looking to use the number input in conjunction with one of the 3 buttons to determine an integer and value. There might possibly be a way to do this without using a form, but using the form allows me to post it to the server and get the variables I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should resolve your problem methodical.

```
<form action="betconfirm.php" method="post">
<ul id="betValue">
    <li id="gameBalance"><h3>Balance: <?=$balance1?></h3></li>
    <li><h3>Bet Amount:</h3></li>
    <li><input type="number" name="betAmount"></li>
</ul>
<ul id="betSelect">
    <li><button name="Black" value="black">Black</button></li>
    <li><button name="green" value="green">Green</button></li>
    <li><button name="red"   value="red">Red</button></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

When submitted your `$_POST` array will look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [betAmount] => 5
    [red] => red
)
```

Comment: Not trying to take away from the answer, but [didn't I already say that earlier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59012440/problem-with-html-tags-for-php-form-submission?noredirect=1#comment104272879_59012440) @methodical

Comment: You certainly did @FunkFortyNiner but I don't think methodical got it so I framed it as an answer.

Comment: If that was the case I'm sorry; @FunkFortyNiner.